# CSS identifiers in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am working on a project whereby there are two different customers for the application and based on a user's credentials when they log in one of two css classes are applied (CustomerA & CustomerB). The classes hide and show information based on these credentials. This works okay in the main application but when an email template uses this approach there are problems in that both are applied. Is there any way to apply these style rules to the email body as well.

observer

```
def after_save(campaign)
  if campaign.status_changed? && campaign.status == 'Approved'
    CampaignMailer.campaign_approved(campaign).deliver!
  elsif campaign.status_changed? && campaign.status == 'Rejected'
    CampaignMailer.campaign_rejected(campaign).deliver!
end
```

mailer

```
def campaign_approved(campaign)
  @host = Portal.host_for_operator(campaign.operator)
  @campaign = campaign
  mail(:to => [campaign.partner.contact_email] + admins, :subject => "Your Campaign '#{campaign.name}' Has Been Approved", template_path: 'mailers/campaign_mailer', template_name: 'campaign_approved')
end
```

template

```
.companyA

  Company A text

.companyB

  Company B text
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it's not a good practice to use css in your email, as a lot of clients ignore from it.

If you do want to send out a rich html email, it's better to write all styles inline and not in CSS identifiers.